# Get UIWindow without using AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift

I need to add a view directly to the window. I can do this by accessing the window object on the AppDelegate via UIApplication. I intend on making this code as reusable as possible though which makes that method unhelpful. How can I access the UIWindow programmatically without using AppDelegate?

I'm coding in Swift but Objective-C examples may be helpful too.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok, figured this one out myself. You can access it like this:

```
var window : UIWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
```

Swift 5:

```swift
var window : UIWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
```

Note that `keyWindow` was deprecated in iOS 13.0.
If you're targeting iOS 13.0 or higher, [refer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57134259/how-to-resolve-keywindow-was-deprecated-in-ios-13-0).

Comment: this was deprecated, how do you do this in swift 5?

Answer (score 13):

Any view has a reference to the current window.

In a UIViewController:

```
self.view.window
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting errors with that. UIWindow does not have a member named addSubview & UIWindow does not have a member names 'centre'. NB: I'm doing this on a UIView which is trying to add itself to the window when a method on it is called from a UIViewController.

Answer (score 4):

Swift 3 version:

```
let window :UIWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This post was of very poor quality, and needed significant improvements to be useful. Please, could you expand your answer?

Answer (score 4):

The following works with Swift 4 and will safely unwrap the `UIWindow` so that a force cast is not required:

```
if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow { 
    // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the first window with:

```
let window = UIApplication.shared.windows[0]
```