# UIApplication keyWindow behavior changed

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uiapplication

After upgrading from Xcode 10.3.1 to Xcode 11.1 my custom Activity indicator added over all UIView is gone.
It is added to keyWindow like this:

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.addSubview(PKHUD.sharedHUD)
```

And now it's gone below over other UIView:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your UIView may need to be refactored.

Look at the inspector, do see the Buildtime warning:

```
'keyWindow' was deprecated in iOS 13.0: Should not be used for applications that support multiple scenes as it returns a key window across all connected scenes
```

See: [How to resolve: 'keyWindow' was deprecated in iOS 13.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57134259/how-to-resolve-keywindow-was-deprecated-in-ios-13-0)