# UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview not working

Tags: ios13, xcode11, swift5, ios13.2

UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview not working in ios13

i try many options but not find any solutions.
i want every screen status bar make blue color form AppDelegate .

i try this code.

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
         /*  let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first
           // Reference - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57899013/7316675
           let statusBar = UIView(frame: window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame ?? CGRect.zero)
           statusBar.backgroundColor = publicMethod().hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#033d6f")
           window?.addSubview(statusBar)
         */
        let statusBar =  UIView()
        statusBar.frame = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame
        statusBar.backgroundColor = .blue
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(statusBar)

    } else {
          let statusBar: UIView = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as! UIView
           if statusBar.responds(to:#selector(setter: UIView.backgroundColor)) {
               //statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
               statusBar.backgroundColor = publicMethod().hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#033d6f")
           }
    }
```

here is screenshot  for this issue.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have probably already solved this question by now, but just in case someone else stumbles upon it in the future, I'll answer it with the code I got working.

First of, since you want to run this piece of code from the AppDelegate, I'm assuming you are running it from the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

In that case make sure that you don't run the code until **after** you have called `makeKeyAndVisible()` or else the keyWindow will be nil.

However, when you call *addSubview()* from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` the viewControllers will be added on top of it, and as such it might not be visible (at least that was the case for me, while using a navigationController).

To test this, when running the app click on the *Debug View Hierarchy* button in xCode as shown in the picture.

[image]

You can drag the screen to see the view hierarchy from different angles like in this picture:

[image]

If that is the case, you can make the statusBar the topmost view by setting the zPosition: `statusBar.layer.zPosition = .greatestFiniteMagnitude`

So my full code for this is:

```
func setStatusBar() {
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        let statusBar = UIView(frame: UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame ?? CGRect.zero)
        statusBar.backgroundColor = .blue
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(statusBar)
        statusBar.layer.zPosition = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
    } else {
        let statusbar = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView
        statusbar?.backgroundColor = .blue
    }
}
```

Again, this will not work in iOS 13 if this function is called before `makeKeyAndVisible()`