# iOS 13 isKeyWindow always returns nil

Tags: swift, ios13, uiapplication, keywindow, uiscene

I am wondering why:

```
UIApplication.shared.windows.first { $0.isKeyWindow }
```

always returns nil both in the simulator and on device. You can confirm this by putting a break point in viewDidLoad in any view controller and printing the object to the console.

```
po UIApplication.shared.windows.first { $0.isKeyWindow }
```

The only way I can get the "keyWindow" is by getting

```
UIApplication.shared.windows.first
```

But there is no explicit mention that it is key. What if there are multiple instances of my app on iPad Split view?

Any ideas?

My thinking is, if there is only one window it's key by default and if you're running more than one window on iPad the one that is currently being interacted with will become the key window, however, I haven't tested this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve: 'keyWindow' was deprecated in iOS 13.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58646877/2108547)

Comment: My question is in direct response to that question, so no - it doesn't. Thnx tho.

Comment: Your code never results in `nil` for me.

Comment: Subscribe to the `didBecomeKeyNotification` and `didResignKeyNotification` notifications and observe the behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this?

```
UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first
```

Comment: Same result unfortunately. Thnx tho.