# in iOS 13 [UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window does not work using objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios13, uialertcontroller, uiwindow

I need to display alert from a class which is non-UIView using objective-c.

Below is the code:

```
 UIAlertController *alertVC = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@“Sample” message message:@“hello message” preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

[alertVC addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Okay" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}]];

[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window.rootViewController presentViewController:alertVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

this above does not work anymore and I could not any other alternative for same code in objective-c.
I came across this link [How to resolve: 'keyWindow' was deprecated in iOS 13.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57134259/how-to-resolve-keywindow-was-deprecated-in-ios-13-0) but solution is in Swift,not in objective-c .

Thanks

Comment: just try the same words in objective c

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in iOS 13, this expression...

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window.rootViewController
```

...is `nil`. That's because the window property belongs to the *scene* delegate, not the *app* delegate. You would do better to access the window by way of the UIApplication *itself*. For example, look through the application's windows and find the one that is key.

Comment: For Objective-C code, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58447461/341994

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to present the viewcontroller in key window which will create exception. Try this code

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Tap!" message:message preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
UIAlertAction *action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
[alert addAction:action];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case most simple would be to use the following as replacement of your last code row

```
[UIApplication.sharedApplication.windows.lastObject.rootViewController 
    presentViewController:alertVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: @sia, would my additional answer yes changed anything? )) ... give it a chance - try!