# 'keyWindow' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 13.0 in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios13, uiwindow, uiscenedelegate

This is my simple button action to show a XIB file which is actually a bar code scanner in Objective-C.

```
 - (IBAction)startCamera:(id)sender {
    BarcodeVC * controller = [[BarcodeVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"BarcodeVC" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    
    //[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
     UIWindow * currentwindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
     [currentwindow.rootViewController presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
  }
```

But unfortunately, a warning comes which is:

> `keyWindow` is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 13.0

I know that since **iOS 13** supports the multiple scenes, but Is there any way to solve this in Objective-C? I have seen Swift versions, but I was unsuccessful with Objective-C.

Comment: Have you checked this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57134259/how-to-resolve-keywindow-was-deprecated-in-ios-13-0/58447461#58447461)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the window through AppDelegate class like..

```
BarcodeScannerVC * controller = [[BarcodeScannerVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"BarcodeScannerVC" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

//[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
UIWindow * currentwindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window;
[currentwindow.rootViewController presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Here i changed to get currentwindow line only so just change it.

```
UIWindow * currentwindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window;
```