# How to get safe area top and bottom insets in Swift 5

Tags: swift

I am looking for a way to get safe area inset values for the top and bottom of the screen (to position content correctly in order to make it not covered by a notch or software home button).

I looked around stackoverflow and was able to find this approach, however I am getting deprecation warning in XCode saying that keyWindow should not be used.

```swift
let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
let topPadding = window?.safeAreaInsets.top
let bottomPadding = window?.safeAreaInsets.bottom
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After iOS13 `keyWindow` concept in iOS anymore as a single app can have multiple windows. So just take the first one :

```
    let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first
    let topPadding = window?.safeAreaInsets.top
    let bottomPadding = window?.safeAreaInsets.bottom
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the view controller view to get the safe area, or you can solve the deprecation as below:

```
let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first
let topPadding = window?.safeAreaInsets.top
let bottomPadding = window?.safeAreaInsets.bottom
```

See also : https://stackoverflow.com/a/57899013/3172445

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```
let topPadding: CGFloat
let bottomPadding: CGFloat
        if #unavailable(iOS 15) {
            topPadding = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets.top ?? 0
            bottomPadding = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 0
        } else {
            topPadding = UIApplication
                .shared
                .connectedScenes
                .flatMap { ($0 as? UIWindowScene)?.windows ?? [] }
                .first { $0.isKeyWindow }?.safeAreaInsets.top ?? 0
            
            bottomPadding = UIApplication
                .shared
                .connectedScenes
                .flatMap { ($0 as? UIWindowScene)?.windows ?? [] }
                .first { $0.isKeyWindow }?.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 0
        }
```