# How to use UIWindowScene.windows on iOS 15?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwindow

Currently, with iOS 14.6, I can call a function in my app that displays a share sheet using the following code:

```
func share(link: URL) {
    let activityView = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [link], applicationActivities: nil)
    UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(activityView, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Since iOS 15 beta, Xcode tells me **"'windows' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: Use UIWindowScene.windows on a relevant window scene instead"**. How can I update this so that my share sheet will work properly in this new version? Thanks!

Comment: let allScenes = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
                    let scene = allScenes.first { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }
                    
                    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
                        windowScene.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(SFSafariViewController(url: url, configuration: conf), animated: isAnimated, completion: nil)
                    }

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/58031897/5790492

Answer (score 105):

**(Tested with iOS 15.2 running on Xcode 13.2.1)**

Improving on [Rachid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68397379/10967642), here is a **Swiftier version**:

```swift
extension UIApplication {
    
    var keyWindow: UIWindow? {
        // Get connected scenes
        return self.connectedScenes
            // Keep only active scenes, onscreen and visible to the user
            .filter { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }
            // Keep only the first `UIWindowScene`
            .first(where: { $0 is UIWindowScene })
            // Get its associated windows
            .flatMap({ $0 as? UIWindowScene })?.windows
            // Finally, keep only the key window
            .first(where: \.isKeyWindow)
    }
    
}
```

If you want to find the presented `UIViewController` in the key `UIWindow` , here is another `extension` you could find useful:

```swift
extension UIApplication {
    
    var keyWindowPresentedController: UIViewController? {
        var viewController = self.keyWindow?.rootViewController
        
        // If root `UIViewController` is a `UITabBarController`
        if let presentedController = viewController as? UITabBarController {
            // Move to selected `UIViewController`
            viewController = presentedController.selectedViewController
        }
        
        // Go deeper to find the last presented `UIViewController`
        while let presentedController = viewController?.presentedViewController {
            // If root `UIViewController` is a `UITabBarController`
            if let presentedController = presentedController as? UITabBarController {
                // Move to selected `UIViewController`
                viewController = presentedController.selectedViewController
            } else {
                // Otherwise, go deeper
                viewController = presentedController
            }
        }
        
        return viewController
    }
    
}
```

You can put this wherever you want, but I personally added it as an `extension` to `UIViewController`.

This allows me to add more useful extensions, like ones to present `UIViewController`s more easily for example:

```swift
extension UIViewController {
    
    func presentInKeyWindow(animated: Bool = true, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?
                .present(self, animated: animated, completion: completion)
        }
    }
    
    func presentInKeyWindowPresentedController(animated: Bool = true, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIApplication.shared.keyWindowPresentedController?
                .present(self, animated: animated, completion: completion)
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I'm running iOS 15.2 and I added both extensions and the warning still occurs in xCode saying, "'windows' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: Use UIWindowScene.windows on a relevant window scene instead." What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you cleaned the build folder and rebuilt the project? Are you sure you're not using `.windows` somewhere else? I just tested using XCode 13.2.1 running iOS 15.2 and it builds just fine.

Comment: For me I had to remove the line `.filter { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }` to get it to work. A better working solution can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58031897/12218938

Comment: You can omit `UIApplication.shared` from the `keyWindow` getter, since `UIApplication` is a singleton, hence, when you access `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow`, you already have access to the `connectedScenes` from within the getter.

Comment: Works like charm, i was stuck for so long due to this.

Comment: We could improve it more, to avoid this warning "First Where Violation: Prefer using `.first(where:)` over `.filter { }.first` in collections. (first_where)"  replace first two lines with this in keyWindow variable `.first(where: { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive && $0 is UIWindowScene })`

Comment: @wristbands that was critical. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: how crazy we gotta go throught all the trouble just to get the window

Comment: let scenes = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
let windowScene = scenes.first as? UIWindowScene
let window = windowScene?.windows.first