# 'UIActivityViewController' doesn't work on iOS 15 iPad

Tags: swift, ipad, uiactivityviewcontroller, ios15

I used this code:

```
    let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: nil)
  
    if let popoverPC = activityController.popoverPresentationController {
        popoverPC.sourceView = centerView
    }
    self.present(activityController, animated: true, completion: {})
```

This code worked on iOS 14.5 for iPad, after install iOS 15 it's doesn't work.

any idea ?

my `UIActivityViewController` empty area, look screen

[image]

Comment: Question: If you don't use `popoverPresentationController`, does it work? It's to see if the issue is about `popover` or only `UIActivityController`...

Comment: I encount the same issue [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69496428/uiactivityviewcontroller-becomes-blank-on-ios-15). No solution yet.

Comment: Hi, the answer in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69567746) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Found a similar issue on iPadOS 16. Resolved by adding

```
popoverPC.sourceRect = CGRect(...) /* arbitrary rect */
```

or

```
popoverPC.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection(rawValue: 0)
```