# Admob crash on iPad with Window container should not be nil

Tags: ios, swiftui, admob

I am trying to integrate Admob. SDK version is 9.0.

I copied the code from

https://medium.com/geekculture/adding-google-mobile-ads-admob-to-your-swiftui-app-in-ios-14-5-5073a2b99cf9

It's working fine on iPhone Device and iPad Simulator. However, it crash on iPad Device with iOS 15.

The error log is

```
*** Assertion failure in -[GADOMIDStateWatcher adSessionDidBecomeActive:], GADOMIDStateWatcher.m:75

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Window container should not be nil'
```

It look like bugs on Admob and I am not sure about that.

Is there any other same issues like me before ? Did you fix that issue ?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please provide full crash log or backtrace from debug console.

Comment: It looks like `var ad = OpenAd()` is *to early* place, try to move it into app delegate did finish launching callback.

Comment: @Asperi thanks for comment. After commenting, it's same issue. OpenAd() for the "App Open Ads". It's not issue and only crash on banner Ads.

Comment: Look at the console it seems you have a better message. Admob seems to be telling you to handle as error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem.  Downgrading the AdMob SDK to 8.13.0 seems to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the issue and fixed like following.

```swift
extension UIApplication {
    
    var keyWindow: UIWindow? {
        // Get connected scenes
        return UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
            // Keep only active scenes, onscreen and visible to the user
            .filter { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }
            // Keep only the first `UIWindowScene`
            .first(where: { $0 is UIWindowScene })
            // Get its associated windows
            .flatMap({ $0 as? UIWindowScene })?.windows
            // Finally, keep only the key window
            .first(where: \.isKeyWindow)
    }
    
}
```

UIApplication extension code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/68989580/215939

```swift
func loadBannerAd() {
        let frame = view.frame.inset(by: view.safeAreaInsets)
        let viewWidth = frame.size.width

        //Updates the BannerView size relative to the current safe area of device (This creates the adaptive banner)
        bannerView.adSize = GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth(viewWidth)

        let request = GADRequest()
if let scene = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.view.window?.windowScene {
            request.scene = scene
        }
        
        bannerView.load(request)
    }
```

The main problem is

I need to set the scene in request

```
let request = GADRequest()
if let scene = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.view.window?.windowScene {
            request.scene = scene
}
```

After that , working fine on the iPad.

Comment: Why you did not set UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes to false in project settings ? It will be a better solution I guess.