# Issue Key.window was deprecated in iOS 13

Tags: swift

I have the following code and do not know how to handle the issue that key.window was deprecated user iOS 13.0 - Any suggestions on how to solve:

```
guard let navController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController else { return }
                        
guard let controller = navController.viewControllers[0] as? HomeController else { return }
controller.configureViewComponents()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve: 'keyWindow' was deprecated in iOS 13.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57134259/how-to-resolve-keywindow-was-deprecated-in-ios-13-0)

Comment: No, unfortunately not.