# Getting the window size for iPad, supporting multiple scenes?

Tags: ios, size, screen, ipados, splitview

I need to get informations about the screen size for the current scene in an iPad application. Assume this snippet as an example

```
var body: some View {
        let sceneSize = getCurrentSceneSize()
        
        Rectangle()
            .fill(.red)
            .frame(height: 200)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .overlay {
                Text("\(sceneSize.width, specifier: "%.0f")x\(sceneSize.height, specifier: "%.0f")")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }

    }
}

func getCurrentSceneSize() -> CGSize {
        return UIApplication
            .shared
            .connectedScenes
            .compactMap { ($0 as? UIWindowScene)?.keyWindow }
            .last?
            .frame.size ?? .zero

    }
```

I got the `getCurrentSceneSize` implementation from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58031897/3393800) answer, and most of the times it seems to work, where most of the times means:

1. There is a single instance of the app running.
2. The app is opened as a split view, and it doesn't get resized (the split view's thumb isn't dragged).

However this code appears to break when:

1. The app is opened as a split view and it gets resized through the thumb, in this case the update isn't triggered unless both the split views are instances of my app.
2. If both the split views are instances of my app, each instance gets its size correctly updated, unless I close it and open it from background, in which case both instances think their width is 1/3 of the screen width.
3. When used with Stage Manager, the size isn't updated when passing to full screen mode, and the other way around.

So my question is: is there any way to reliably get the updated scene size that works across iOS and iPadOS?