# Getting rootViewController for iOS13+ & Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, background, voip, apn

I am trying to get rootViewController like:

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
```

This is working while the app is in the foreground.

My app has also indication for "Voice over IP" and it uses APN for delivering Push Notifications when a new call is being made.
The issue with getting a rootViewController occurs, when the user accepts Voip call from iOS Push Notification handlers and starts the app from background (or terminated but re-instantiated).

Is there any concise way how to deal with this situation so I can get a ViewController when app is started from background?

Comment: It should always work regardless of the way the app was started. Maybe the problem is in when you call that. Maybe you do it before the app loads UI.

Comment: Could be that UI is not loaded. Is there any way how to check if the UI is loaded? I guess it is only via viewDidLoad, or?

Comment: You may look into this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58031897/465677